# Video validation showing error: The video must be a file of type:

Tags: laravel

I have to upload video in a laravel project and i have this validation rule

```
'housevideo' =>['mimetypes:video/x-ms-asf,video/x-flv,video/mp4,application/x- 
     mpegURL,video/MP2T,video/3gpp, video/quicktime,video/x-msvideo, video/x-ms-wmv, video/avi,video/qt,max:90000','required_without_all:houseimage'],
```

But when i upload video, i get this error

> The video must be a file of type: video/x-ms-asf, video/x-flv, video/mp4, application/x-mpegURL, video/MP2T, video/3gpp, video/quicktime, video/x-msvideo, video/x-ms-wmv, video/avi, video/qt, max:90000.

This is the details of the video

[image]

what might be the problem

dd($request->all());

[image]

blade.php

```
<form method="POST" action="/houses" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf
     <div x-data="imgPreview" x-cloak>
            <x-input-label for="housevideo"  :value="__('Video')"/>        
            <x-forminput name="housevideo"  type="file" class="block mt-1 w-full" accept="video/*" 
            x-ref="myFile" @change="previewFile"/>
            <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('housevideo')" class="mt-2" />    
                <template x-if="imgsrc">
                    <p class="w-40">
                    <img :src="imgsrc" class="imgPreview">
                    </p>
                </template>
             </div> 
</form>

 <x-input-label for="housevideo"  :value="__('Video')"/>        
        <input name="housevideo"  type="file" class="block mt-1 w-full" accept="video/*" />

['mimetypes:video/x-ms-asf, video/x-flv, video/mp4, application/x-mpegURL, video/MP2T, video/3gpp,   video/quicktime, video/x-msvideo, video/x-ms-wmv, video/avi, video/qt','required_without_all:houseimage'],
```

Comment: You can try the validation rule: 'video' => ['mimetypes:video/*', 'max:90000', 'required_without_all:houseimage'],

Comment: how does the input in the <forn> look?

Comment: it should be a string, not an array maybe?
like `'video' =>'mimetypes:video/x-ms-asf,video/x-flv,video/mp4,application/x- 
     mpegURL,video/MP2T,video/3gpp, video/quicktime,video/x-msvideo, video/x-ms-wmv, video/avi,video/qt,max:90000','required_without_all:houseimage',` instead of `'video' =>['mimetypes:video/x-ms-asf,video/x-flv,video/mp4,application/x- 
     mpegURL,video/MP2T,video/3gpp, video/quicktime,video/x-msvideo, video/x-ms-wmv, video/avi,video/qt,max:90000','required_without_all:houseimage'],`

Comment: definitely there should be no spaces after commas

Comment: I believe spaces after commas is the problem. Try putting video/mp4 first or just deleting them

Comment: @KarlHill, i get this error  The housevideo must be a file of type: video/*, max:90000.

Comment: max:90000 is not a file type.

Comment: you should separate next rule (max) with pipe symbol (|)

Comment: max:90000 should be in a separate string or separated by pipe

Comment: it is working in MRE i created. what laravel version are you on?

Comment: works even with linebreak in the middle of the string, spaces after commas after video/mp4 and probably ill formed max:90000

Comment: I just did <input type="file" ...> and showed error, none of the x-ref and other x- stuff, nor `@change`. Also no imgsrc
What are these anyway. Is `@change` for some js framework?

Comment: @wojand thanks for your suggestions. I have updated my code as shown in the updated question. 'atchange' etc were used to preview the video before submitting the form. I have removed that. But still it doesnt work. I uploaded video before now but suddenly, it stopped working. Could this be from laravel? I use laravel 8.

Comment: Well, if you have version control (like git) you can try see what happenned and when.
Please fix the max rule in the meanwhile. Consider reviewing code of the <something here>Request class, maybe showing it. My understanding is that it fails immediately in controller (on injection of the custom request class, automatic validation)

Comment: I will repeat one important thing: PLEASE FIX THE `max:...` thing. It shouldn't be in the same string, or at least raises everybody's suspicion which is just as bad. Maybe the upload fails because it is too big? But this is displayed erroneously?

Comment: @wojand, I removed max:... totally and i got same error. The way forward that i choose was no validation for video. i dont know how safe it is but for now, it is serveing

Comment: any news? were you able to fix this?